# plain text editor that can delete lines

Tags: text-editor

I keep to do lists on my computer using plain ASCII text (.txt) files that I sync with Dropbox.

I just got an Android tablet and I'd like a text editor that I can use to edit those files.  I need only two features above the basic text editor:

- Ability to delete a line (the ability to select a single line would also work)
- Ability to move a line up/down one line (this one is optional)

Any Android text editors good for lists?

Answer (score 1):

I find [Epistle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kooklab.epistle) a useful text editor that syncs with a Dropbox folder, it's not the most advanced editor but can handle both plain text and Markdown formatted plain text (as used here). It uses the built-in Android text selection features, so you can select a line by dragging the text selection arrows to both ends.